# How can i convert 0d0a to 0a?

Tags: regex, perl, grep

I am coding a perl code dos2unix.

This is a simple example code.

```
$hex =~ s/0d0a/0a/g;
```

I'm found one problem.

The well was converted to 000a00 if 000d0a00.

The problem is when 00d0a000.

When the conversion is not the case.

So I changed the code.

```
$hex =~ s/0d0a(?=(..)+$)/0a/g;
```

Issue has been resolved.

But, speed is too slow.

Is there another way to fix this?

Comment: You want to convert `0d0a` if it has an even amount of characters before/after it?

Comment: Whats wrong with the `perl -pe 's/\r\n\z/\n/'` ?

Comment: Have you converted this data to hex characters? If so then the solution is not to do that

Comment: @jm666, Won't work on a Windows machine (or if `PERLIO` contains `:crlf`). Don't know if he wants his script to be portable or not.

Answer (score 1):

> I am coding a perl code dos2unix.

So you want to convert CR LF to LF.

```
use open IO => ':raw';  # Prevent Perl from doing any implicit
binmode STDIN;          # changes to the input or output.
binmode STDOUT;         # 
while (<>) {
   s/\r\n/\n/g;
   print;
}
```

or

```
use open IN => ':crlf';  # Have Perl change CR LF to LF when reading,
binmode STDIN, ':crlf';  # and prevent Perl from doing any implicit
binmode STDOUT;          # changes to the output.
print while <>;
```